# Restoring incremental backup of Postgres

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have restored basic backup successfully of Postgres. However, after that I have tried to restore incremental backup of Postgres(it was a couple of write to test table), and it had a couple of WAL files and some WAL files with .backup at the end. I have tried to put them into my pg_wal archive directory, that I'm using in the following restore command at postgresql.conf:

```
wal_level = replica
max_connections = 100
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/16/main/pg_wal/wal_archive/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/16/main/pg_wal/wal_archive/%f'
restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/16/pg_wal/wal_archive/%f %p
```

After putting them into */var/lib/postgresql/16/pg_wal/wal_archive* I have tried to restart a couple times postgresql, however my new added WAL files still was not applied. Worth to mention that it seems like restarts did not trigger recovery mode, as restore_command usually executed from that mode.

Any help or advices is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not an incremental backup; what you are trying to do is called "point in time recovery", which you initiate by placing a `recovery.signal` in the Postgres data directory and restarting the server. There are more details to how that works, which you can find in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-ARCHIVE-RECOVERY).

Until the incremental backup/restore functionality makes it to Postgres 17, the only other option is to use [pgBackRest](https://pgbackrest.org/configuration.html#section-repository/option-repo-block).

Comment: Incremental backup has already made it into v17.

Comment: Yeah byt v17 hasn't made it to the release yet, has it?

Comment: Right. Perhaps I misunderstood; it sounded like you were saying that it isn't in v17 yet.